# systemd-timesyncd on Debian 8 (fails silently?)

Tags: debian, logs, systemd, ntp

I'm having troubles on a Debian 8 installation to get systemd to synchronise time properly. NTP has been enabled with `timedatectl set-ntp true` and `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd` reports:

```
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-02-04 13:25:22 CET; 5h 49min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
 Main PID: 302 (systemd-timesyn)
   Status: "Idle."
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
           └─302 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
```

No errors can be found in any logs, though timesyncd still seem to refuse to synchronise properly, as `timedatectl status` reports:

```
NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
```

Time-section (the only section) from timesyncd.conf:

```
[Time]
Servers=0.dk.pool.ntp.org 1.dk.pool.ntp.org 2.dk.pool.ntp.org 3.dk.pool.ntp.org 
#Servers=0.debian.pool.ntp.org 1.debian.pool.ntp.org 2.debian.pool.ntp.org 3.debian.pool.ntp.org
```

Finally running ntpdate manually against one of the servers in the configuration, `ntpdate 0.dk.pool.ntp.org`, synchronises just fine.

May it be so that there's an error somewhere on my behalf, but if so, shouldn't timesyncd or systemd report this?

Comment: Do you have a `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` file? If so, post the contents of that file in the question. If not, that's probably the issue.

Comment: Configuration from ```/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf``` added to the question.

Comment: is your system able to reach the NTP pool servers over NTP? "ntpq -c peers" would be one test

Comment: Also, check if `ntpd` service is running with `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd ntpd`. You should see ntpd service active and running. If not, you'll have to enable `ntpd` service with `sudo systemctl enable ntpd`.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your access to the time servers specified *are blocked* via firewall/network or your local host-based firewall (iptables). I got the same errors on Debian Jessie 8.6 such as below:

```
systemd-timesyncd[21869]: Using NTP server 193.225.118.163:123     (hu.pool.ntp.org). 2016-12-27T11:57:24.832779+01:00 xxxxxx systemd-timesyncd[21869]:     Timed out waiting for reply from 193.225.118.163:123 (hu.pool.ntp.org).
```

Note that the command **systemctl status systemd-timesyncd** should show the same or similar output to you on your terminal. If not, try restarting the service and look out for *Timed out waiting for reply from ...* . If you have successful connection to the NTP server, the service logs should show you the following after restarting the service:

```
Dec 27 11:58:14 xxxxx systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Dec 27 11:58:14 xxxxx systemd-timesyncd[21895]: Using NTP server X.Y.Z.ZZ:123 (your.ntp-server.com).
```

After this, the command **timedatectl status** should display the line (among others):

```
...
NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
...
```

Note that you don't have to have anything specified in the relevant section of */etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf* . If you commented out the Servers line, then the the service defaults to 0-3.debian.pool.ntp.org time servers.